# timer wont start with start/pause toggle button

Tags: swift, swift3, timer

I want to make a timer that gets triggered by one button to start the timer. When the timer is running, I want the same button to pause the timer.

I handle this behaviour mainly within the IBAction of the button label:

```
@IBAction func btn_start(_ sender: Any) {        
    if timerIsRunning == false {        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)            
        timerIsRunning = true                       
    }

    if timerIsRunning == true {            
        timer.invalidate()            
        timerIsRunning = false            
    }        
}
```

I recognized that I can trigger the start button several times and the timer was triggered also severalt times, so that the timer was speeding up in the end.
To prevent this behaviour I introduced the timerIsRunning:Bool with the unexpected result, that the timer does not start anymore :-/

This is my timer function that is triggered by the timer:

```
func runTimer() {        
    if timeInSeconds >= 0 {        
        timeInSeconds = timeInSeconds - 1            
        updateTimerLabel()            
    }        
}
```

Can anyone explain this? and give me a helping hand?

Comment: `timerIsRunning = true; if timerIsRunning == true` Uh-huh.

Comment: @matt What do you mean? Can you explain?

Comment: he means what I basically wrote in my answer as well, you set the variable to `true` and in the next statement you check its value against true.

Comment: ah okay, now I see,... OMG such a poor noobie mistake. No wonder that it did not work at all. Now I can laugh about it :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `return` after you start the timer, or use `else`. Otherwise you always `invalidate` the newly created timer instantly in the second `if` block in your method:

```
@IBAction func btn_start(_ sender: Any) {        
    if !timerIsRunning {        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)            
        timerIsRunning = true                       
    } else {            
        timer.invalidate()            
        timerIsRunning = false            
    }        
}
```